# Java GraphQL Annotations: Specify List Field

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

How do I have to specify a List Field in the java-graphql-annotations framework?
Unfortunately I could not found any [documentation](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-annotations/blob/master/README.md) about specifying list fields.

This example produces an error:

```
// Bean class
public class MyBean {    
  @GraphQLField
  public List<?> getList() {
    return null;
  }      
}

// instantiate object type
GraphQLAnnotations.object(MyBean.class);
```

Exception Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.WildcardTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
at graphql.annotations.DefaultTypeFunction$ListFunction.apply(DefaultTypeFunction.java:133) ~[graphql-java-annotations-0.13.1.jar:na]
at graphql.annotations.DefaultTypeFunction$ListFunction.apply(DefaultTypeFunction.java:120) ~[graphql-java-annotations-0.13.1.jar:na]
at graphql.annotations.DefaultTypeFunction.apply(DefaultTypeFunction.java:304) ~[graphql-java-annotations-0.13.1.jar:na]
at graphql.annotations.DefaultTypeFunction.apply(DefaultTypeFunction.java:37) ~[graphql-java-annotations-0.13.1.jar:na]
at graphql.annotations.GraphQLAnnotations.getField(GraphQLAnnotations.java:391) ~[graphql-java-annotations-0.13.1.jar:na]
at graphql.annotations.GraphQLAnnotations.getObjectBuilder(GraphQLAnnotations.java:208) ~[graphql-java-annotations-0.13.1.jar:na]
at graphql.annotations.GraphQLAnnotations.getObject(GraphQLAnnotations.java:167) ~[graphql-java-annotations-0.13.1.jar:na]
at graphql.annotations.GraphQLAnnotations.object(GraphQLAnnotations.java:173) ~[graphql-java-annotations-0.13.1.jar:na]
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method must be return a Type for List:

```
...
@GraphQLField
public List<Object> getList() {
  return myValue;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you either create a dataFetcher class that returns the list and bind it to the field with the `@GraphQLDataFetcher(FetcherClass.class)` annotation above the field (and then the method is never called so you can return null), or you can return the list in the method itself.

By the way - I don't think it can work with wildcards, you must specify a type